# Elki plots from pure Java API

Tags: java, elki

I've been searching for a way to export ELKI generated visualization into SVG file, which can later be displayed on my application. However, I could not find any example code which uses typical java constructors. My goals are:

- input Results in a Visualization.
- set VisualizerParameterizer constructor, adding the previous Visualization.
- set ExportVisualizations constructor properly to write the file.

For instance, let's say I already have an OutlierResult instance and now I want to plot the scores using BubbleVisualization and produce an SVG file? How can I do that using the pure Java API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some classes like `VisualizerParameterizer` can be a bit annoying to set up *manually*, because this involves finding all desired visualization factories from the service loader - there is a plug-in layer there, that allows to add new visualizations to be rendered automatically.

Because of this, the easiest way is to use the parameterization API, for example (git style):

```
ExportVisualizations export = new ELKIBuilder<>(ExportVisualizations.class)
    .with(ExportVisualizations.Parameterizer.FOLDER_ID, "folder")
    .build();
```

or if you are still using an old release / do not like builders:

```
ListParameterization params = new ListParameterization();
params.addParameter(ExportVisualizations.Parameterizer.FOLDER_ID, "folder");
ExportVisualizations export = ClassGenericsUtil.parameterizeOrAbort(
                                  ExportVisualizations.class, params);
```

Because you only need to give mandatory parameters, and it can construct nested objects. In this case, it will also construct the `VisualizerParameterizer`, so you can also add options for that class, such as

```
.with(VisualizerParameterizer.Parameterizer.ENABLEVIS_ID, "scatter")
```

to only enable scatter plot visualizations.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.visualization.VisualizerParameterizer$Parameterizer.collectFactorys(VisualizerParameterizer.java:329)
 at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.visualization.VisualizerParameterizer$Parameterizer.makeOptions(VisualizerParameterizer.java:317)

Comment: Could you provide a complete example from Database to BubbleVisualisation? I searched the official tutorials and how to, however, I could not find any. Currently, I implemented your solution only replacing "folder" by the folder absolute path. Currently, I have the exception mentioned above.